# Working for German company with French passport talent residence permit

Tags: germany, resident-permit, france, citizenship, residence-cards

I hold French “passeport talent” four-year residence permit and have already worked in France for last three years. I am being offered a job by a German company who are happy with me working from France. My questions are:

1. If I work on permanent employment contract from German registered company but receive salary in my French bank account, am I legally authorized to do that?
2. Will I be eligible to extend my residence permit from France after expiry of my current card?
3. How will it impact my citizen application eligibility in France (next year will be my full 5 years of working in France so I’ll be eligible for application)
4. How above scenario changes if I work rather as a free lancer with German company and file my taxes in France myself?

Comment: Will the work contract be based  on French law, with taxes etc. done in France? In such a case there should be no problem.

Comment: I echo @Mark Johnson's question and I have a few additional ones if it is not the case: if not, does this mean that you will be working in Germany but living in France (i.e. "frontalier")? Or will you be working remotely?

Comment: This seems *extremely* difficult, if not impossible. Is your prospective employer aware of your situation and willing/able to fulfill all administrative requirements on the French side or are they counting on you to figure it out?

Comment: did you find answers to these questions?